# Karma/Jasmine doesn't find html file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, karma-runner

I have a spec that opens a `iFrame` with a local html file as src.

```
var template = document.createElement('iframe');
template.src = 'template.html';
```

I tried to find the file via javascript at runtime but file is not found and Karma shows a 404 warning.

I have read and tried [preProcessor](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/preprocessors.html), proxy, about the `base/` url fix and still nothing... would be very happy to have some input here.

Comment: Configure a proxy and then start Karma. Try to reach the page with the URL yourself: can you find it?

Comment: @MarcoCI, I did not managed to reach the file from the browser while karma is running. Tried `http://localhost:9876/base/template.html`, `http://localhost:9876//template.html` and other variants with no success :/

Comment: How did you configure the proxy? What's the path of the `html` file and what's the karma configuration one?